# How to call a method located inside a C# DLL, from VB.Net, with late binding

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, late-binding

I can't get a grip on how the various "Init", "Accumulate" ... methods work, to enable calling a method located inside a DLL, from VB.Net code.

Let's say the method to call has the following signature :

```
public double ComputeMeanPosition(ref SortedList<DateTime, double> posByTime)
```

Would you please kindly point me to an actual example of the use of the methods, or simply give me a few hints as how to actually pass the parameters to the method, call it and fetch the results ?

@Olivier Jacot-Descombes: I definitely prefix the class name by the namespace name, but yet fail to be able to reach the object. In fact I am surprised that your kind suggestion does not involve the following methods, displayed through introspection of the loaded DLL :

```
Type: MyClassName
        Method: Void Init()
        Method: Void Accumulate(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble, System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime, System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean)
        Method: Void Merge(MyClassName)
        Method: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble Terminate()
        Method: Void Write(System.IO.BinaryWriter)
        Method: Void Read(System.IO.BinaryReader)
        Method: Boolean Equals(System.Object)
        Method: Int32 GetHashCode()
        Method: System.String ToString()
        Method: System.Type GetType()
```

**EDIT**

In fact I have a code similar to the following one, that successfully manages to inspect the DLL and gets several types and methods out of it, giving the following results above for the method I would like to call.

Here is the code

> ```
>         For Each oneModule As Reflection.Module In useAssembly.GetLoadedModules()
>             Console.WriteLine("   - " & oneModule.Name)
>             For Each oneType As System.Type In oneModule.GetTypes()
>                 Console.WriteLine("     Type: " & oneType.Name)
>                 For Each oneField As Reflection.FieldInfo In oneType.GetFields()
>                     Console.WriteLine("        Field: " & oneField.ToString())
>                 Next oneField
>
>                 For Each oneMethod As Reflection.MethodInfo In oneType.GetMethods()
>                     Console.WriteLine("        Method: " & oneMethod.ToString())
>
>                     [[ ADD "Invoke" here ?]]
>                 Next oneMethod
>             Next oneType
>         Next oneModule
> ```

At the end, it seems that the [[...]] is at the place where the Invoke method should be called to call the method of my choice, but that is where I'm stuck... Would I need to build an object before calling it ? How should I pass it the parameters  ? How to get the result ?

Comment: How are you creating the object that you wish to call the methods on?

Comment: Let's say the method is static. It just calculates stuff. So in the VB.Net Code, I have the objects I need to pass to it. I load the DLL, and I would then like to call the method...

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

public class MainClass
{
      public static int Main(string[] args)
      {
           Assembly a = null;
           try
           {
                a = Assembly.Load("YourLibraryName");
           }
           catch(FileNotFoundException e)
               {Console.WriteLine(e.Message);}

           Type classType = a.GetType("YourLibraryName.ClassName");

           object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);

           object[] paramArray = new object[1];    
           paramArray[0] = new SortledList<DateTime, double>();
           MethodInfo mi = classType.GetMethod("ComputeMeanPosition");
           mi.Invoke(obj, paramArray);

           return 0;
       }
 }
```

For VB.NET:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.IO

Public Class MainClass
    Public Shared Function Main(args As String()) As Integer
        Dim a As Assembly = Nothing
        Try
            a = Assembly.Load("YourLibraryName")
        Catch e As FileNotFoundException
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try

        Dim classType As Type = a.[GetType]("YourLibraryName.ClassName")

        Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(classType)

        Dim [paramArray] As Object() = New Object(0) {}
        [paramArray](0) = New SortledList(Of DateTime, Double)()
        Dim mi As MethodInfo = classType.GetMethod("ComputeMeanPosition")
        mi.Invoke(obj, [paramArray])

        Return 0
    End Function
End Class
```

Tested and this worked:

```
 Dim a As Assembly = Nothing
    Try
        a = Assembly.Load("TestLib")
    Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Dim classType As Type = a.[GetType]("TestLib.Class1")

    Dim obj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(classType)

    Dim [paramArray] As Object() = New Object(0) {}
    [paramArray](0) = New SortedList(Of DateTime, Double)()
    Dim mi As MethodInfo = classType.GetMethod("ComputeMeanPosition")
    mi.Invoke(obj, [paramArray])
```

Comment: Oh ... Just a little detail :). I am trying to call the method from VB.Net, not C#.

Comment: @SkippyFastol - Just updated my answer to include what should be a working VB.NET solution

Comment: Unfortunately, after "Dim classType As Type = a.[GetType]("YourLibraryName.ClassName")
", the "classType" variable contains "Nothing". I tried various combinations ("YourLibraryName.ClassName", "YourLibraryName.NamespaceName.ClassName" ...)

Comment: Let me try out this VB.NET code Skippy. I ran the C# code through a VB.NET converted so it might not of converted properly. Let me test it on my end.

Comment: @SkippyFastol -- I just edited my answer and pasted what I tried and it worked just fine. Make sure the DLL file is in the same directory as your application and adjust any names accordingly.

Comment: then I may have a problem with  my library. I can't get "classType" to contain a value other than "Nothing". I will try to get hold of its source code and check how things. Go. Is your example assuming that the called method is static ?

Comment: I just added a code snippet I have and that manages to introspect the library up to the point where the Invoke method may need to be called. That is where I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Skippy -- Try using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) or [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). It will show you the source code of your DLL file and you should be able to look at the namespaces. Or you can send me the DLL and I will try it out on my end

Comment: thanks so much. For the ILSpy & dotPeek + the suggested help.

Comment: Icemanind -- let's say the method I would like to call is "private". Normally, as I create an instance of the object before calling the method on it, it should be callable ?

Comment: Skippy - You can't call a private method. The method you call must be public.

Comment: icemanind -- Got it. Is the mechanism similar in case the method was originally in a 'struct' and not a 'class' ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the actual code, because I'm not in sitting in front of an actual c# editor, but something like this

```
// using System.Reflection required

// first load the external assembly into the appdomain and 
// create an instance of the object
var assembly = Assembly.Load("Path to the Assembly");
var type = assembley.GetType("TheNameOfTheClass");
var ctor = type.GetConstuctor();
var object = ctor.Invoke(); // assuming an empty construtor, else you'll need to pass in data

// next invoke the method
var methodInfo = assembly.GetMethodByName("ComputeMeanPosition");
var param = new SortedList<DateTime, double>();
var result = methodInfo.Invoke(object, new object[] { param });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call this method as if was declared like this in VB

```
Public Function ComputeMeanPosition( _
    ByRef posByTime As SortedList(Of DateTime, Double)) As Double
```

---

Note: I used this online [snippet converter](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx) to convert the C# code to VB. You have to add an empty method body `{}` to the C# method header before converting it.

```
public double ComputeMeanPosition(ref SortedList<DateTime, double> posByTime) {}
```

---

As this method is not declared as `static` in C# (`Shared` in VB) you first need to create an object. The method is most likely declared inside a class. Let's say the class was named "MyClass", then you would have to write something like this

```
Dim posByTime = New SortedList(Of DateTime, Double)()
Dim obj = New MyClass()
Dim result As Double = obj.ComputeMeanPosition(posByTime)
```

If the constructor (the `New` method) declares arguments, you will have to pass them when creating the object

```
Dim obj = New MyClass(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Depending on what `ComputeMeanPosition` expects, you will have to add items to the list `posByTime` before calling it.

---

If the method was declared as `static` in C# (`Shared` in VB), you would qualify it with the class name, instead of creating an object.

```
Dim posByTime = New SortedList(Of DateTime, Double)()
Dim result As Double = MyClass.ComputeMeanPosition(posByTime)
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you load the assembly dynamically you will probably do something like this

```
Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\SomePath\MyDll.dll")
Dim obj As Object = ass.CreateInstance("MyClass", True) 

Dim posByTime = New SortedList(Of DateTime, Double)()
Dim result As Double = obj.ComputeMeanPosition(posByTime)
```

And you will have to set the `Option Strict Off` for late binding.

---

If the constructor requires arguments, you will have to pass them to another overload of `CreateInstance`

```
Dim args = new Object() { arg1, arg2, ... }
Dim obj As Object = ass.CreateInstance("MyClass", True, _
    BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance, Nothing, Nothing, _
    args, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Comment: I am not sure I expressed myself clearly : in fact I have not access to the DLL before the launch of the VB.Net Code :). I actually dynamically load the DLL during the execution of the program... Your suggestion may work though.

Comment: I had missed the "Option Strict Off" (it was "On").

Comment: The only issue is the "Dim result As Double = obj.ComputeMeanPosition(posByTime)" leads to "Object variable or With block variable not set."

Comment: Obviously `obj` is `Nothing` beacuse the class with the name you specified was not found. Try to use the full name qualified with the namespace.

Comment: Just updated the main post with a question and an introspection result.