# How to import DLL file in vb.net(visual basic) programmatically?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 files: **lib.dll** & **executor.exe**.

## lib.dll

```
Public Module Module1
   Public Function Abc()
      MsgBox("I am dll")
   End Function
End Module
```

I want to import **lib.dll** and use its function in **executor.exe**.
I know **lib.dll** can be added via **visual basic reference**,
But when I place **lib.dll** in another directory, then it shows errors.
I want to import dll from a path something like as shown below.

```
imports "C:\Users\root\Desktop\lib.dll"
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Module1.Abc()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: [How to call a method located inside a C# DLL, from VB.Net, with late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450935/how-to-call-a-method-located-inside-a-c-sharp-dll-from-vb-net-with-late-bindin)

Comment: @JQSOFT thanks but this link didn't solved my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks but I was asking for vb.net (visual basic) code,
NOT C#.

Comment: Create a new `Class` with a proper name, move the method to the new class, change the `Function` to a public `Sub` since it returns nothing, and try again the same link and do the necessary changes.

Comment: Do you pass the right path of your `DLL` file? the second link by _jmcilhinney_ shows you how. Not so hard to extract the idea from c# code.

Comment: @JQSOFT sir as you said: <br>create class<br>change function to sub<br>

I got this but it doesn't return anything `Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1
    <Obsolete>
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\Users\root\source\repos\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll")
            Dim obj As Object = ass.CreateInstance("test()", True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
`

Comment: Try: go to the `EXE` folder and run it as Administrator. Could be a security issue. Also you can edit your post to add what you've tried. Hard to read the code from comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify folder where runtime will search for DLLs in .config file using "probing" element.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location

Comment: this answer is somewhere according to my point that we should able to use **DLL** from a path, But in my **XML** file, I didn't find any **DLL** path.

Comment: You did not read that MSDN documentation correctly. It is NOT path to DLL file, but path to folder, where DLL files are. .NET Framework will try to find referenced DLLs in this folder(s).